# Removing duplicates from CSV yet keeping column headers

Tags: sorting, powershell, export-to-csv

I have a working powershell script that removes duplicates in a csv file, but it sorts the column headers within the data, which I don't want, and cannot figure out a way to keep the column headers.

```
Get-Content C:\testdata.csv | ConvertFrom-Csv -Header "Column1", "Column2", "Column3", "Column4" | sort -Unique -Property Column1 | % {"{0},{1},{2},{3}" -f $_.Column1, $_.Column2, $_.Column3, $_.Column4} | set-content c:\output.csv
```

The test data csv is as follows:

```
Name,IDNumber,OtherNumber,UniqueCode
Tom,10,133,abcd
Tom,10,133,abcd
Bill,4,132,efgh
Bill,4,132,efgh
Bill,4,132,efgh
Lefty,3,122,ijkl
Lefty,3,122,ijkl
Lefty,3,122,ijkl
Lefty,3,122,ijkl
```

Is there a way to accomplish this with Powershell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `Import-Csv` and `Export-Csv` makes this process much easier as they are built to deal with csv files and headers.

```
Import-Csv "C:\testdata.csv" | Sort-Object * -Unique | Export-Csv "c:\output.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Bet me to it by seconds, @James C! ;)

Comment: James C thank you very much, that is fantastic!  I just learned something today, that solution is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but try this...

```
Import-Csv -Path 'C:\path\to\File.csv' |
  Select * -Unique |
  Export-Csv 'C:\path\to\NewFile.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Select -Skip 1 to skip over the original header column:

```
Get-Content testdata.csv | Select -Skip 1 | ConvertFrom-Csv -Header "Column1","Column2","Column3","Column4" | sort -Unique -Property Column1 | % {"{0},{1},{2},{3}" -f $_.Column1, $_.Column2, $_.Column3, $_.Column4} | set-content output.csv
```

Comment: Adding this as an alternative answer in case there's some specific reason for doing it without import-csv, e.g. if they want to specifically convert the header names to numbered columns.